# How to bind to a specific Item property within the style setter of ItemContainerStyle?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an issue that isn't breaking anything in my code, it's just causing a bunch of obnoxious warnings and time spent resolving binding expressions. I would like to solve it.

Specifically, here is one of the warnings I get:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Color; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'SolidColorBrush'; target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')

(I get two more for Opacity and DashStyle, but for brevity, I'll stick with color for this question).

Here is the relevant code:

```
<z:ClassWithMyItems ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
   <z:ClassWithMyItems.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType={"x:Type z:MyItem}">
            <Setter Property="Pen">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Pen Thickness="2.0" options:Freeze="True" DashStyle="{Binding DashStyle}">
                        <Pen.Brush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color={Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}" Opacity="{Binding Opacity}" />
                        </Pen.Brush>
                    </Pen>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </z:Feature.ItemContainerStyle>
</z:ClassWithMyItems>
```

*(NOTE: The DataContext is set to an instance of a MyClassWithItems that has a set of 'Items', and each Item has a 'Color' property).*

From what I can tell, xaml is first looking within the DataContext of the **SolidColorBrush**, and complaining that it's null. Then, after a couple of tries, it finally decides to look at the DataContext of the **Item**, upon which it finds the 'Color' property and stops complaining. (I know this because it eventually resolves and renders correctly).

This is a bunch of work that can be saved if it knew to look at the DataContext of the 'Item' first instead of the SolidColorBrush. For the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You could try to have a Binding Converter that returns a Pen instead of a Color, and declare `<Setter Property="Pen" Value="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToPenConverter}}"/>`.

Comment: That's a really clever solution - the only trouble is that I actually have three properties I need to bind to: Color, Opacity, and DashStyle (I'll edit my post). I'm not sure you can use a converter with 3 binding values...

Comment: Please post a [`MCVE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's much easier that way for you and anyone else.

Comment: @CharlesB: Bind to the object itself and then cast the value to the appropriate type in your converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Clemens you could use a converter that returns a `Pen`. Just bind to the `MyItem` object itself:

```
public class PenConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MyItem myItem = value as MyItem;
        if (myItem == null)
            return value;

        Pen pen = new Pen();
        pen.DashStyle = myItem.DashStyle;
        pen.Brush = myItem.Brush;
        //...
        pen.Freeze();
        return pen;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type z:MyItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <local:PenConverter x:Key="converter" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Pen" Value="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: This solution works and the warnings are no more - thank you. I think I was hoping for a binding syntax trick that just told the pen to look at the DataContext above it, but this also does the trick.